# How to loop design in SSRS report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssrs-2012

I have a report design that have been used for a while.

Now i want to create multiple pages of the same report looping with different records.

Is there any way to do this, to loop the design..
either looping it how to get the lookup-function to register as a valid function in an expression.

I use two datasets in the report

I started by making one tablix cell and putting the entire design into this one cell, which worked nice, except i have to use one tablix with "Dataset2" and it doesn't allow me to do this because if they are nested, the inner scope has to use the same dataset as the outer scope.

The report designer can't recognize the "lookup" function which i try to put in a expression of this tablix, and using a subreport for such a small task seems like too much.

Any ideas?

Here's a quick screenshot of what I'm working with:
Everything uses dataset1 except that one tablix that needs to be dataset2...
[image]

Heres a image of my lookup-function that gives an error:
[image]

Comment: Add a reproductible sample dataset and the expected results in order to help you.

Comment: Either you need to use the lookup function or a subreport - I don't see any other way (other than you adding the data in your query). If you post the **Lookup** expression that you tried then someone can try to help fix it.

Comment: I added an image of the code and error now. Will the lookup-function allow me to get all records from dataset2 that has the same key, or will it take first only? 

I use report data provider from ax2012 to get the dataset btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i got this right.

If you want to loop a single page ssrs design put the whole design in a 1x1 tablix with grouping on whatever parameter you like.

- If any part of your design use data from another dataset inside of this tablix, you have to use a sub report...
  It isn't that much work, but to get the correct parameter in i actually had to make a report data provider and contract + design for the subreport(which just consisted of a single table) which was a pain in the ass. none the less it worked, and all is good.